# Which Lilypond engraver handles accent marks?

Tags: lilypond, engraving

In the following example (from my recent question, [Globally removing engravers from LilyPond](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/124502/21766)), I've managed to remove every engraver I need except for one: whichever engraver is responsible for the accent (>) on the bass clef's B.

[image]

What engraver do I remove to automatically get rid of such marks?

```
\version "2.20.0"
\language "english"

global = {
  \key e \minor
  \time 2/2
  \partial 4
}

right = \relative c' {
  \global
  e8_\mf r8 |
  g4 fs8 e ds4 e8 fs |
  b,4\( cs8 ds e4\)
}

left = \relative c {
  \global
  g8( fs |
  e4) a b4._> a8 |
  g4 fs e
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "upper" \right
    \new Staff = "lower" { \clef bass \left }
  >>
  \layout { 
    \context {
      \Staff
        \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
    }
    \context {
      \Voice
        \remove "Stem_engraver"
        \remove "Rest_engraver"
        \remove "Phrasing_slur_engraver"
        \remove "Slur_engraver"
        \remove "Tie_engraver"
        \remove "Dynamic_engraver"
        \remove "Dots_engraver"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Extending on Ramillies part: Articulations are handled *both* by the `Script_engraver` as well as the `New_fingering_engraver`. These differ slightly in how they work. `Script_engraver` will listen to articulation type events, while the `New_fingering_engraver` does only acknowledge note heads and adds articulations from the `articulations` property of the cause.

Note that events handled by the Script_engraver will then be removed from this `articulations` property, as can be seen here.

```
#(define (eng context)
   (make-engraver
    (acknowledgers
     ((rhythmic-head-interface engraver grob srceng)
      (display (ly:event-property (ly:grob-property grob 'cause) 'articulations))
      (newline)))))

% prints empty list
\score {
  c->
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Voice
      \consists #eng
    }
  }
}

% prints list with articulation event
\score {
  c->
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Voice
      \consists #eng
      \remove Script_engraver
    }
  }
}
```

This means that usually articulations will be handled by the `Script_engraver`. If you remove that one they will instead be handled by the `New_fingering_engraver`. So you also need to remove that one.

Answer (score 4):

That's actually an interesting question, and I've hit a bit of block here. But first of all, I would like to show you how to get this kind of info from the docs.

First we need to know what kind of object these articulations are. Often, the best way is to skim the basic docs (in this case, [1.3.1 "Expressive marks attached to notes"](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-attached-to-notes)). After each section, there is a "see also" part that also has links to the internals reference. Here we can see that it links to `Script` and `TextScript` objects. So we inspect these pages, and it turns out that `TextScript` is the object that handles all the markups, while `Script` handles the articulations. So the articulations are `Script`s.

Next, we can look at its [internals reference page](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/internals/script), and we see that it's drawn by `Script_engraver`. And looking at the [`Script_engraver`'s page](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/internals/script_005fengraver) in turn, we see that it's used by `Voice` (see the line "`Script_engraver` is a part of the following contexts:" at the bottom). So it looks like adding `\remove "Script_engraver"` should do the job.

However — it does not!! I'm sorry, but I have no idea why — perhaps someone else will be able to enlighten us both. However, nothing is lost, because you can put pretty much any kind of `\override`s and related commands into the `\context` blocks as well. So if you add `\omit Script` into the second context block in your code, it will do what you want.

Comment: I swear I read that first page three or four times earlier today :-) But the next few steps were largely new to me, so thank you! I'll wait to see what others say, but your solution works great.

Comment: For reasons that are a little difficult to explain, you also need to remove `New_fingering_engraver` in addition to `Script_engraver`.

Comment: @ABOUSAMRAJean Hi Jean! Is there any reason why this is this way? As I understand the code any articulation type event or text script type event should be handled by `Script_engraver` and `Text_engraver`, without ever being touched by the `New_fingering_engraver` unless you remove one of these engravers. Do we have script-type events that are neither articulation-type nor text-script-type?

Comment: Hi Valentin. I guess you answered your own question in your answer? Or did I misunderstand the question?